# How to use Javascript to load XML into DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have an XML file like the following.

```
<term>
<category>General</category>
<english>Addiction</english>
</term>

<term>
<category>General</category>
<english>Blood pressure</english>
</term>
```

And I write a javascript program which consists of two loops. aiming to read the XML and load the XML into the DataTable. The first loop is used to store the data of column of table and the second loop is used to load the data and write into the HTML file.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  readTerm(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
xhttp.send();    

function readTerm(xml) {
var numberOfTerms = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("term").length;
var category = [];
var english = [];
var tableContent = ' ';

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++) {
    category.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("category")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    english.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("english")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++) {
  tableContent += "<tr><td>"+category[i]+"</td><td>"+english[i]+"</td></tr>";
}

document.getElementById("termData").innerHTML = tableContent;
}
```

I have embedded the following link in the following order.

```
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.jss
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
```

However, I can see the table output but I cannot read the number of entries which set by the `DataTable.js`. Is it a good practice to use Javascript to read XML into the HTML or does my method is wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your answer. What is exactly the result you want to have?

Comment: What you are doing is fine, but you would probably do better if you query terms with `getElementsByTagName("category")` and such instead of the whole doc. As for the question, it is unclear what does "I cannot read the number of entries" mean - you did read the number of entries, it was `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("term").length`. So, what is actually wrong?